# Put something in my href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How is it possible to put something in data-notifications in jQuery?

See below my href which is composed like this:

```
<a href="#" class="OCnotifications" data-notification="">Notification (s)</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `attr`

```
$('.OCnotifications').attr("data-notification", "something");
```

or use [the data API](http://api.jquery.com/data/), which doesn't actually modify the attribute though, but you can use the data API to retrieve and set consistently on the element instead of using `.attr` if you are using `.data`.

```
 $('.OCnotifications').data("notification", "something");
```

Using the data API.

- You can avoid doing DOM operations by accessing it using the attr.
- Has support for vanilla JavaScript as well using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) which is supported in newer browsers.
- Any casting (conversion to numeric, parsing JSON to an actual object, etc.) are automatically handled in the data API. So you won't need to do them separately.

*Also note that using .attr or .data as a getter will only get the attribute/data value of the first element in the collection if the selector matches multiple elements.*

Comment: Thanks it's what i wanted !